# In react axios, my object is going going out side of the array?

Tags: reactjs, get, axios, output, state

So I made an API request using `axios` with react and tried storing the json into an array in the state. But when is logged the state, it gave me 2 outputs: One was an empty array and another was an object which was returned. Don't know whats happening. Tried everything I can.

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class CustomerPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      customerData: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const {
      match: { params }
    } = this.props;
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5001/api/customer/data/${params.number}`)
      .then(res => {
        // console.log(res.data)
        const customerData = res.data;
        this.setState({
          customerData: customerData
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    const { customerData } = this.state;



    console.log(customerData) //this returns the empty state array and the
                             //object from axios

    return (
      <div>
        Your Info
        {customerData.map(customer => (
          <li key={customer._id}>{customer}</li>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(CustomerPage);
```

It gave me the output:

> TypeError: customerData.map is not a function

Comment: can you add that object too?

Comment: I checked your code. That's solid. Can you share your object? Because with simple mock your code is working fine.

Comment: Hi @sushant, your question seems super valid, however in order to help the best way, could you please share which part of your code is logging those _two outputs_? Is the commented line `console.log(res.data)`? Could you please try avoiding update `state` to prevent the `TypeError` and only log the _response_ from the `GET` request?